# debootstrap from Intel Atom (i686) to AMD Sempron (AMD 64)

Tags: debian, system-installation, cpu-architecture

I'm working on setting up a minimal Debian install on a USB stick, and am just trying to wrap my head around `debootstrap` and differences in architectures. I want to create a system to run on AMD64 [(AMD Sempron 145)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempron) from i686 [(Intel Atom N450)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_atom). As far as I understand, the atom is a 64 bit processor, so can I just do this:

```
debootstrap --arch=amd64 wheezy /mnt/foobar
```

Or do I have to follow one of the more complicated [cross-debootstrap procedures](http://wiki.debian.org/EmDebian/CrossDebootstrap)?

#### extra info:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                2
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
CPU socket(s):         1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 28
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               1666.444
L1d cache:             24K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              512K
```

Comment: You could possibly use one of the higher level systems like sbuild instead of using debootstrap directly.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks, I didn't know about `sbuild`, I'll keep it in mind for next time. I chose to use `debootstrap` mostly for the learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debootstrap needs to be able to run executables in the target system. If that'll work, then it'll be fine. If not, it'll blow up obviously.

I'm pretty sure it should work as long as you're running a 64-bit kernel. You can run a 64-bit kernel with a 32-bit userland (but not vice versa). So, worst case, you may need to install a 64-bit kernel on your current Atom system.

Also, note that deboostrap may not make everything 100% ready to boot. E.g., I'm not sure fstab will be set up, or a bootloader installed, etc. If possible, it'll likely be easier to run the Debian Installer on your Sempron box instead.

Or, if you're trying to build a live "CD", see http://live.debian.net/

Comment: This was pretty much exactly right. The kernel I had installed was 32-bit, but installing a 64-bit kernel was as easy as `sudo apt-get install linux-image-2.6-amd64`. After rebooting and using the 64-bit kernel, `debootstrap` worked basically perfectly. And I know there are simpler ways to do an install, I chose this method mostly for the learning experience.